# Installing and loading packages with a single function

Tags: r, function, install.packages

I have been trying to write a function to replace library and install.packages functions of R that loads the functions if it is installed and installs and loads if it is not. It works fine for the first case but when I try to install a function using this even after installing it gives the 'there is no package called ...' error. The packages get installed correctly but I failed to install and load in the single run of the same function. I added the sleep command hoping it would fix it but it did not. Anyone know why?

```
insist = function(name){
    #enables entering package name without quotes
    name = substitute(name) 
    name = as.character(name)

    if (!require(name, character.only = T)) {
        install.packages(name)
        Sys.sleep(2)
        library(name, character.only = T)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/trinker/pacman after installing `p_load` does exactly what you're after.

Comment: He seems to use a tiered structure, to install packages and load them but I couldn't find anything fundamentally different in his code that would enable his to work and explain why mine fails. Will check throughly when I have more time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message is actually coming from `require()` and not `install.packages()` or `library()`. I bet the package it still being added to your search path (at least it was for me). So I think you have to be more aggressive about suppressing that warning. Try this.

```
insist = function(name){
    #enables entering package name without quotes
    name = substitute(name) 
    name = as.character(name)

    if (suppressWarnings(!require(name, character.only = T, quietly=T))) {
        install.packages(name)
        library(name, character.only = T)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not the case. The initial `require` of line 6 gives out the warning, package ... is not available. I have no problem with that but the error comes from library's attempt to load the package in the end. As a final result, I have an error thrown at me and the package is not loaded but only installed.

Comment: Did you step through the function with the debugger to confirm? If that's the case, then i could not replicate your error. My code above runs error/warning free for me with the packages i tested.

Comment: Weirdly it doesn't give an error. It turns logical.return True by itself for some reason and return a warning instead. But it's clearly from library not require. I even tried manually setting logical.return to false but it didn't work
`Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘corrplot’`